# Как запросить загрузку файла у пользователя в telegram боте?

Tags: telegram-bot

Требуется отобразить пользователю кнопку, по нажатию которой будет отображен стандартный диалог telegram для отправки медиа. Аналогично кнопке отправки контакта.

Далее, пользователь стандартным же способом делает и отправляет новое фото или изображение из галереи.

Возможно такое?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, такой диалог невозможно вызвать с помощью Bot API. Да и, собственно, для чего это нужно? В случае с контактом или геолокацией - это упрощение для пользователя, так как отправляется сразу контакт или локация самого пользователя автоматически, без дополнительных диалогов. А в случае с выбором файла все действия будут просто дублироваться.

---

Вообще, хорошо бы сразу писать о задаче, которую пытаетесь решить - тогда можно было бы поискать и предложить альтернативу. А так - просто ответ **нет**.

Comment: Задача простая - "подтолкнуть" пользователя к загрузке изображения, выведя ему стандартный диалог выбора из галереи.